# 2 method Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, exception

I keep getting the Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException error message. I have tried switching stuff around, but I keep having this problem

I have tried declaring the variables in different methods, but nothing is seeming to work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {

    public static double drivingCost(double drivenMiles, double milesPerGallon, double dollarsPerGallon) {
        double totalCost = (drivenMiles / milesPerGallon) * dollarsPerGallon;
        return totalCost;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double milesG;
        double dollarsG;
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        milesG = scnr.nextDouble();
        dollarsG = scnr.nextDouble();
        drivingCost(10.0, milesG, dollarsG);
        milesG = scnr.nextDouble();
        dollarsG = scnr.nextDouble();
        drivingCost(50.0, milesG, dollarsG);
        milesG = scnr.nextDouble();
        dollarsG = scnr.nextDouble();
        drivingCost(400.0, milesG, dollarsG);
    }
}
```

The problem is:

Write a method drivingCost() with input parameters drivenMiles, milesPerGallon, and dollarsPerGallon, that returns the dollar cost to drive those miles. All items are of type double. If the method is called with 50 20.0 3.1599, the method returns 7.89975.

Define that method in a program whose inputs are the car's miles/gallon and the gas dollars/gallon (both doubles). Output the gas cost for 10 miles, 50 miles, and 400 miles, by calling your drivingCost() method three times. 
Output each floating-point value with two digits after the decimal point.

The input is: 20.0 3.1599

Expected output: 1.58 7.90 63.20

Comment: Your problem description is contradicting itself. When your code throws an exception (and I dont see how it could do that) ... how can you **also** have something being printed?! Especially given the fact ... that there is NO print statement in your code. So: please read [mcve] and update your question accordingly. And either drop the exception part, or include the exact stack trace you got, telling us which line it supposedly comes from.

Comment: alright, chill out

Comment: Just saying: when you want our help, you need to be precise about your problem. The "better" your input the easier it is to help you, and the faster you will receive helpful feedback.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   
   /* Define your method here */
   public static double drivingCost(double drivenMiles, double milesPerGallon, double dollarsPerGallon) {
      double totalCost = (dollarsPerGallon * drivenMiles / milesPerGallon);
      return totalCost;
}
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      /* Type your code here. */
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      double milesPerGallon = scnr.nextDouble();
      double dollarsPerGallon = scnr.nextDouble();
      double drivenMiles = 1;
      System.out.printf("%.2f ", drivingCost(drivenMiles, milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon) * 10);
      System.out.printf("%.2f ", drivingCost(drivenMiles, milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon) * 50);
      System.out.printf("%.2f\n", drivingCost(drivenMiles, milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon) * 400);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

drivenMiles divided by milesPerGallon then multiplying by dollarsPerGallon will give you the price of gas per mile driven.
Note: drivenMiles just needs to be passed to drivingCost in this case. That is why the integers 10, 50 and 400 are added to call.

since drivingCost has the parameters milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon and drivenMiles in that order, you have to call the method with the same order of the parameters.

"%.2f" will get two decimals to the right. Adding \n will start a new line afterward.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   
   public static double drivingCost(double milesPerGallon, double dollarsPerGallon, double drivenMiles) {
      // calcuating the cost of gas
      double totalCost = (drivenMiles / milesPerGallon) * dollarsPerGallon;
      return totalCost;
    
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      double milesPerGallon;
      double dollarsPerGallon;
      milesPerGallon = scnr.nextDouble();
      dollarsPerGallon = scnr.nextDouble();
      // order of the call to the method is important, printing cost of gas for 10, 50, and 400 miles
      System.out.printf("%.2f ",drivingCost(milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon, 10));
      System.out.printf("%.2f ",drivingCost(milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon, 50));
      System.out.printf("%.2f\n",drivingCost(milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon, 400));
   }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `scnr.nextDouble();` six times in your main function. Make sure you provide six arguments of type **double** when running your program. Currently, you are passing less that six arguments and `scnr.nextDouble();` is throwing the exception as it could not find the next argument of type double.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   public static double drivingCost(double milesPerGallon, double dollarsPerGallon, double drivenMiles) {
  return (drivenMiles / milesPerGallon) * dollarsPerGallon;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  double milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon;
  
  milesPerGallon = input.nextDouble();
  dollarsPerGallon = input.nextDouble();
  
  System.out.printf("%.2f ", drivingCost(milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon, 10));
  System.out.printf("%.2f ", drivingCost(milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon, 50));
  System.out.printf("%.2f\n", drivingCost(milesPerGallon, dollarsPerGallon, 400));
  
    }
}
```